# Augment jackson's JsonParser

Tags: java, json, jackson

Currently my applications can do as follows. It can read a JSON configuration such as:

```
{
  "a": 5,
  "b": 3
}
```

Into a POJO that looks like:

```
public class AddConf {
  private Number a;
  private Number b;
  // constructor, getters and setters
  public int add() {
    return a.intValue() + b.intValue();
  }
}
```

Then we can call the add function a return a result of 8 in this example. I would like to augment com.fasterxml.jackson.databind somehow to allow my JSON to have placeholders. So let's say when my configuration I don't know what value b will be until runtime, then I might make a configuration like this:

```
{
  "a": 5,
  "b": $b_placeholder$
}
```

To signify that b value will be provided at runtime. Obviously the above is not a valid JSON, and by default jackson throws an Exception (as it should) when it attempts to parse this with ObjectMapper's readValue. Ideally, I would like to read the above "JSON" (or something equivalent) into a POJO that looks something like this:

```
public class AddConf {
  private Map<String,String> usedPlaceholders;
  private Number a;
  private Number b;
  // constructor, getters and setters
  public int add(Map<String,String> runtimeConf) {
    if (usedPlaceholders.contains("a")) {  // if "a" was a placeholder
      a = runtimeConf.get(usedPlaceholder.get("a"));
    }
    if (usedPlaceholders.contains("b")) {  // if "b" was a placeholder
      b = runtimeConf.get(usedPlaceholder.get("b"));
    }
    return a.intValue() + b.intValue();
  }
  public void setPlaceholder(String key, String value) {
    usedPlaceholder.put(key, value);
  }
}
```

The idea is when deserializing the augmented JSON above, it would call setPlaceholder("b", "b_placeholder") instead of setting the value b and therefore when add is called, it will use values in the passed in runtimeConf Map instead of values from the JSON to do its configuration.

Given this, I have 2 questions:

Is there an easier way to accomplish my goal of having "placeholders" in my JSON configuration? It seems if I was to implement my idea here, I would have to override some of the Jackson classes. I would have to override the com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser to allow $ as a valid token in some scenarios, I would also have to write custom derserializers for all my configuration POJO (such as AddConf). This would likely casade into me having to override much of the jackson code base, which I would rather not do.

If I were to take this approach to override some of the default jackson classes, how might I go about doing that?

I am currently using jackson 2.6.0

Comment: Check usage of `@JsonCreator` in a constructor, the so called *delegate* constructor. And maybe you could make the placeholder a string attribute, so it is valid json and you don't have to work with non-json data.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for annotation `@JsonRawValue`, use of which allows specifying EXACT contents to include as value, while still taking care of adding necessary separators.